# How to use html form input field's value in addition expression?

Tags: javascript, html

I have two text input fields in html form and need to add the field's value when *add button* is clicked.

I have used `parseFloat` function but they seem to be concatenated instead of addition.

```html
 <input type="text" id="x"/>
 <input type="text" id="y"/>
 <button id="add">ADD</button>

 <h1 id="displayResult"></h1>

 <script>


  var x = document.getElementById("x");
  var y = document.getElementById("y");
  var add = document.getElementById("add");
  var displayResult = document.getElementById("displayResult");
  x = parseFloat(x);
  y = parseFloat(y);     
  add.addEventListener('click', ()=>{
     displayResult.innerHTML = x.value + y.value
  })

  </script>
```

Comment: `x` and `y` are objects. you want to use `document.getElementById("x").value` instead, to get the value

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to parse the value not the element

```
x = parseFloat(x);// x here not value but the element
```

```js
var x = document.getElementById("x");
var y = document.getElementById("y");
var add = document.getElementById("add");
var displayResult = document.getElementById("displayResult");
add.addEventListener('click', function() {
  displayResult.innerHTML = parseFloat(x.value) +parseFloat(y.value)
})
```

```html
<input type="text" id="x" />
<input type="text" id="y" />
<button id="add">ADD</button>
<h1 id="displayResult"></h1>
```

Answer (score 0):

you need to get value from `x` & `y` first before using `parseFloat`

```js
var x = document.getElementById("x");
var y = document.getElementById("y");
var add = document.getElementById("add");
var displayResult = document.getElementById("displayResult");

add.addEventListener("click", function () {
  x = parseFloat(x.value); // here
  y = parseFloat(y.value); // here
  displayResult.innerHTML = x + y;
});
```